# Mac El Capitan 10.11 GCC Disable Abort Trap

Tags: c, macos, gcc, osx-elcapitan

This question has been asked before for previous version of OSX, but the answers provided no longer seem to work for OSX 10.11.

I am trying to execute a simple buffer overflow example on my Mac. I am compiling using these flags:
-fno-stack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -fno-sanitize=memory

However, I still receive an "Abort Flag: 6" message whenever I attempt a buffer overflow.

Edit: Corrected spelling of "FORTIFY" from "FORITFY"

Can anyone tell me how to compile the code correctly using GCC?

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that you're not really using GCC on El Capitan.  You need to look up info on the LLVM compiler.

Comment: Also, if `-D_FORITFY_SOURCE=0` is really a copy and paste from your command, it contains a misspelling. The "T" should be after the first "R".